# Software to change fan trigger CPU temperature

Tags: hardware

Cooler on my **HP Pavilion G6-1102ER** notebook starts working only when CPU temperature exceeds 80-85 degrees Celsius (with 50/50 chance actually). But I even don't care because of the speaker sound that signals me that the cooling fan isn't spinning.

This repetitive beep is annoying, especially after 5 minutes. I have already cleaned the computer, replaced the cooling fan with the original one, but the problem remains.

Is it possible to somehow programmatically set the CPU temperature at maximum when the cooling fan starts spinning?

Comment: While you cannot change the temperature itself just by software, it might be possible to tune the fan to have it kick-in earlier (or later). But to recommend something along these lines, we need a few more details: Which OS? Must the software be free, or how much would you be willing to spend?

Comment: On most PCs the temperature at which the fan starts is set in the BIOS settings lowering the trigger value would be better than trying to lie about the current CPU temperature.

Comment: If it's an Intel i-CPU, setting the max. CPU to 99% in the power options prevents it from "boosting", which again prevents it from becoming too hot, which in turn prevents the fan from spinning. This works very well for me for several years now, since I don't need the extra boost power.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest fitting a hardware temperature controller such as the one below - you can then set the temperature at which the fans start to any values that you select.

[Advance](https://www.advancetec.co.uk/nzxt-sentry-2-controller-meter-touch-screen-fan-for-upto-5-fans-5-25-bay.html) [image]

Comment: *installs in a 5.25" bay* I don't think that's going to help the OP with his notebook - neither with other hardware devices.

Comment: @JanDoggen - Ooops I didn't think to check the model number and find out that it was a notebook - the question didn't mention that detail ... I think that I will leave the answer up as it may be helpful to people who have desktop PCs.

Comment: This is a hardware recommendation, not software... I'm sure there are valid reasons, in some cases, to recommend hardware instead in an answer, but you should at least explain why software is insufficient.